# Regarding the validation of the input file separator in Perl

Tags: perl, field, separator

I have csv input file in Perl which is tab separated.
I would like to add a check if it find anything other than tab as field separator then it  should through error message. I am new to perl I don't know how to check.

Example of my input file, my file having only two field:

```
10001027^I1000102713921-1274^M$
10010121^I1001012113921-1234^M$
10000104^I10010126139211-9999^M$
10010119^I10010126139211-9999^M$
```

Comment: How can you tell if something other than a tab is a field separator?

Comment: I agree with ikegami -- please define what are not acceptable field separators.  After those are defined, you can search the file to make sure those unacceptable field separators do not exist.

Comment: semicolon(;),comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to validate the file would be to check that each line had a single tab.

```
while (my $line = <$file>)
{
    if ($line !~ /^[^\t]+\t[^\t]+$/)
    { 
        #Handle malformed line.
    }
}
```

If you plan to split the line into elements anyway, you could use the split output for error checking:

```
while (my $line = <$file>)
{
    my @fields = split "\t", $line;

    if (@fields != 2)
    {
       #Line did not split into two elements, indicating improperly formed line.
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.if ($line !~ /^[^\t]+\t[^\t]+$/) it works...But I have another issue. If I have more than one tab means number of field grater than 2  I should display error message incorrect number of field.Since I am checking  for one tab it doesn't satisfy my  else  part when I am trying to show the number of field greater than 2.If am giving condition if my array contain less than two field then it should do all the validation for field else should display incorrect number of field

Comment: @puspa, the above regex only matches if there is *exactly one tab in the line*, so it should cover that case, too.

Comment: Please let me know if no of field separator grater than one tab then I should display the error message in correct number of field.

Comment: But I want to display the error message incorrect number of field ...Not invalid separator if tab more than 1

Comment: Hi Dan really great help and thanks a lot for hep....Sorry to disturb you again.Instead of find exactly one  tab I would like to find out exactly one semicolon(;).If semicolon found then I would like to mark as invalid record.If you will be  able to help me it will be great.I have to deliver this script on Thursday.

Comment: It should be easy to replace `\t` with semicolon in the above regex.  If you appreciate the help, you could upvote/accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.I didn't replace I just use your first line which is finding out exactly one tab.

Comment: Hi dan,If you know about this please help me.My input file having so many record.Some of the record which is failing due to database check I am inserting into  a temp table and setting the flag=1.I want to get the line number of those record I am inserting into temp table.The record I am not inserting into temp table I am getting line number easily since I am splitting the file using same function.For database insert I am using different function.How  I will get line number for the record I am inserting into temp  table.

Comment: I answered your question.  If you have new question(s) they should be posted as new questions, not asked in the comments.  Also, people will be more likely to help you if you upvote and accept helpful answers to your previous questions.